# Why can't I pickle an instance of unicodecsv.reader?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I need to `cPickle.dump` an object that stores an instance of  `unicodecsv.reader` class. When I try to do so, the process terminates with exception:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type '_csv.reader'>: it's not the same object as _csv.reader
```

I've found that this might be problem when you have multiple different imports of the same object but that's not my case.

Could you give me a hint on what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `csv.reader` objects can't be pickled so `unicodecsv.reader` objects can't be pickled either. It doesn't normally make sense to pickle `csv.reader` objects because they're normally used with files, which also can't be pickled.

There's no simple solution to your problem. You could either define your own [custom pickling methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol) that tell's the pickler how to pickle the object without pickling the `csv.reader` object, or you can rewrite the implementation of the object so it doesn't need to store an instance of `unicodecsv.reader`.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was pickling list(unicodecsv.reader).